# Find the limit: $\lim_{n\to\infty} \left (1+ \frac {1}{2^2}+ \frac {1}{3^3}+...+\frac {1}{n^n} \right)$

Tags: calculus, limits, closed-form, riemann-zeta

> Does the limit:
>   $$\lim_{n\to\infty}  \left (1+ \frac {1}{2^2}+ \frac {1}{3^3}+...+\frac {1}{n^n} \right)$$
>   admit a closed form?

I know only Riemann-Zeta function.I've just discovered this sum.

Comment: I know only riemann zeta

Comment: It's a constant, which equals $$\int_{0}^{1} x^{-x}\,dx\approx \frac{3675}{2846}.$$ See *Sophomore's dream*.

Comment: So? Please edit the question with an attempt before your question is closed as off topic.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Is it possible could you add a detailed answer? I dont understand. :(

Comment: Are you looking for a closed form?

Comment: @barto ýes I looking for closed form.

Comment: @Math I edited your question to make that clear then.

Comment: Why was the question downvoted, I dont know...

Comment: I saw dublicate.Okay.